# Making POST requests from C++ to REST server

Tags: c++, rest, http, post, libcurl

I am trying to make POST request from a C++ program which will insert/update entries in a database.

I am currently using *libcurl* but I am forced to strcat() the POST parameters and convert integers to char arrays:

```
//first parameter: name=user.name
char str[] = "name=";
strcat(str, user.name);

//converting int to char array: &number=user.number
strcat(str, "&number=");
uint16_t number_int = user.number;
stringstream number_str;
number_str << number_int;
string number_temp = number_str.str();
char *number_char = (char*) number_temp.c_str();
strcat(str, number_char);

//the whole thing: "name=user.name&number=user.number"
char *data = str;
char addr[] = "192.168.1.26:5000/api/v0.1/users";
char *address = addr;

auto curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, address);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);

  CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  curl = NULL;
}
```

I don't know if I am using the library correctly, but this is the best way I found.

I am just trying to do this :

```
curl -X POST 192.168.1.26:5000/api/v0.1/users --data 'name=someName&number=someNumber'
```

where 'someName' and 'someNumber' are variables.

EDIT: Is there a better way of doing POST requests with different parameters with C++ (avoiding the conversion of the int to char array and the concatenation)?

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Why don't you just work with `std::string` and at the end when you pass your string to curl convert it via `myData.cstr()`?
Keep in mind you also should urlencode the parameter pairs via `curl_easy_escape`